# Problema con app_name textos en diversos idiomas

Tags: android, facebook

Tengo la necesidad de encontrar una solución a un problema con la `app_name` de mi proyecto android.

La idea es que me debería poder tener `app_name` tanto para inglés y para español, pero solo me permite para uno. ¿Alguna salida?

Comment: con el app_name te refieres al  <application  android:label del manifest?

Comment: Se supone que si. Porque al cambiar de idioma es lo que empieza a fallar

Comment: Existe la documentación oficial de Android que explica muy bien el tema de los múltiples lenguajes en las aplicaciones Android. La documentación se encuentra en español para un fácil entendimiento. [Documentación sobre múltiples idiomas en Android](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html?hl=es-419)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para ese caso puedes usar el soporte multilenguaje definiendo un string llamado `app_name` en cada archivo strings.xml definido para un lenguaje diferente.

```
 <string name="app_name">Mi Aplicación</string>
```

Estes textos además del nombre de la aplicación se pueden aplicar para otros en la aplicación.

#### Soporte multilenguaje en Android

El esquema de localización requiere que crees folders y archivos conteniendo el texto y su identificador en diferentes lenguajes según lo requieras, que serán soportados por tu aplicación.

Por ejemplo, si suponemos que nuestra aplicación soporta idiomas inglés, español y rumano, debemos tener los siguientes folders....

El folder de textos default sería:

```
res/values/strings.xml
```

El folder para agregar los textos en ingles:

```
res/values-en/strings.xml
```

contendría:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="nom">Crazy Dog</string>
    <string name="desc">Crazy dog Transportation, the best company</string>
</resources>
```

El folder para agregar los textos en español es:

```
res/values-es/strings.xml
```

contendría:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="nom">Perro Loco</string>
    <string name="desc">Transportes Perro Loco, la mejor empresa</string>
</resources>
```

El folder para agregar los textos en rumano :

```
res/values-ro/strings.xml
```

contendría:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="nom">Câine nebun</string>
    <string name="desc">companie de transport Câine nebun, cea mai buna companie.</string>
</resources>
```

Tendrías algo similar a esto en tu proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Simplemente esas descripciones definidas en tus `strings.xml` las usas en donde sea requerido en tu aplicación:

```
String strNombre = context.getResources().getString(R.string.nom);
textViewName.setText(strNombre);
String strDescripcion = context.getResources().getString(R.string.desc)  
textViewDesc.setText(strDescripcion);
```

**La gran ventaja es que automáticamente, dependiendo del lenguaje definido en tu sistema operativo carga los textos definidos en el archivo `strings.xml` del lenguaje correspondiente.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

Para solucionar este problema bastaría con hacer que la app soportara varios idiomas. Para ello puedes echarle un ojo a la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html?hl=es-419) de [android](/questions/tagged/android).

Para tu problema concreto del nombre de la App, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

En tu Manifest deberás hacer uso de los recursos string, para que el dispositivo coja el idioma correspondiente automáticamente, para ello se utiliza `@string/` quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApp"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Por otro para agregar compatibilidad con más idiomas, tendrás que crea directorios values adicionales dentro de res/ que incluyan un guión y el código de idioma ISO al final del nombre del directorio. Como por ejemplo **values-en**, quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
MyProject/
    res/
       values/
           strings.xml
       values-en/
           strings.xml
```

Por último tendrás que agregar los valores de string para cada configuración regional en el archivo correspondiente. Por ejemplo:

Español (configuración regional predeterminada), /values/strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Mi Aplicación</string>
</resources>
```

Inglés, /values-en/strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My Application</string>
</resources>
```

Espero te sirva de ayuda